# C++11 std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> from std::cout

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

I'm having trouble storing `std::cout` in a `std::shared_ptr<std::ostream>`.

Since this obviously shouldn't be done:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> p_cout(&std::cout);
```

And this isn't even possible since it's not possible to copy a std::ostream:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> p_cout = std::make_shared<std::ostream>(std::cout);
```

Does someone know a legal workaround?

Comment: This is one of the situation where c++ allow us to shoot in face

Comment: This will be a better question when you explain why on earth you feel the need to wrap `std::cout` in a `std::shared_ptr<std::ostream>`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit For compability with an framework (WIP).

Comment: @Tim: I'm sorry to hear that your chosen framework mandates the passing of streams wrapped in `shared_ptr`s!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why? You think it is bad design? Because I'm co-designing the framework, but it seems to me the best option.

Comment: @Tim: You haven't even finished designing the framework, and already you've found yourself performing ghastly mutations to your client code in order to work around limitations of the framework's API; yes, I'd say that's bad design! Why does the library need to accept smart pointers? It cannot take ownership of the objects. Maybe have it be a template and take a `T*` or perhaps a `P`, where `P` can be substituted by any pointer-like type.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks I'm going to look into that. The `std::shared_ptr` was supposed to eliminate ownership distinctions between for example a `std::ofstream` and `std::cout` as a private class member. I know it's not af fast as templates, but it also isn't as complicated in my situation. That being said, I see that the whole idea is bad design..

Comment: @Tim: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "it's not as fast as templates". Anyway, why can the library function not accept a `std::ostream&`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Since an `std::shared_ptr` counts its references, besides it dereferences. A plain reference won't work since the class needs to function without a stream to.

Comment: @Tim: I know what a `std::shared_ptr` does, but if the function you're passing it to doesn't store or take ownership of the pointer, then there is no reason to do that at all -- you can just pass a normal pointer or reference to the original object. I don't know what you mean by your second sentence.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's a member of a class. So it needs to be stored.

Comment: @Tim: Yikes! Does it really need to?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's an (input/output) stream class for the framework. So, yes, I guess this is my only option..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The requirement you have is strange, but you can of course store a pointer to `std::ostream` in a `shared_ptr<std::ostream>` provided, you take care of a proper disposer action:, e.g.: `std::shared_ptr<std::ostream>(&std::cout, [](void*) {});`

Answer (score 13):

> this obviously shouldn't be done:
>
> `std::shared_ptr<std::ostream> p_cout(&std::cout);`

Indeed, this should **never** be done. The reason is because you don't have ownership of `std::cout` and thus when your last `shared_ptr` goes out of scope it tries to delete `std::cout` (which is plain evil). But you already knew that.

The solution, if you must absolutely use a `shared_ptr` (which I assume is a matter of API compatibility), is to use a custom deleter that does nothing:

```
shared_ptr<std::ostream> p_cout(&std::cout, [](std::ostream*){});
```

Answer (score -1):

shared_ptr will take ownership of the pointer you give it. This means your program will eventually try to delete std::cout (when that last copy of a the initial shared_ptr goes out of scope). This is not something you want to do.

Since you do not need to control the lifetime to std::cout, you could simply pass a std::ostream raw pointer or reference around.

Comment: Ofcourse, the reason for the question... Note the example what shouldn't be done.